# Overriding service provided in component

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've got a problem, where I can't override service provided in component.
The component looks like this:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'c',
    templateUrl: './c.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./c.component.scss'],
    providers: [TestService],
})
export class Component implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _testService: TestService){}
}
```

My usual approach to root provided services looks like this:

```js
class TestServiceMock {
  method(): string { return 'Test' }
}

describe('Component', () => {
    let component: Component;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component>;

    beforeEach(async () => {

        });
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [Component],
            providers: [
                { provide: TestService, useClass: TestServiceMock },
            ],
        }).compileComponents();
    });
```

But this time component still refers to the original service method and in `component.testService.method()` returns `undefined`.

I tried also overriding component before configuring testing module like this, but it also doesn't  mock my service.

```js
TestBed.overrideComponent(Component, {
            set: { providers: [{ provide: TestService, useClass: TestServiceMock }] },
        });
```

Do you have any idea how can I mock this service? I'm pretty sure the problem is because this service was provided in component, not in root as usual.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this, and it has worked for me.

Do it exactly like this:

```
// Create the TestBed module
const testBedModule = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [Component],
});

// over ride after the module has been created
TestBed.overrideComponent(Component, {
            set: { providers: [{ provide: TestService, useClass: TestServiceMock }] },
        });

// compile the components
await testBedModule.compileComponents();
```

Comment: this saved me.  after chasing my tail on a provider override that would not take effect, i was finally able to make it happen with this. thanks!  i am still left wondering why i need to do this, but i think it has something to do with how the service is being injected. i lose my initial mock in the testbed setup. hmmm....

Comment: Since the provider is being provided in the `@Component({` decorator, we cannot mock it in the `TestBed.configureTestingModule`'s providers array. We have to do it with the `TestBed.overrideComponent` approach. Here is an article explaining this situation: https://medium.com/ngconf/how-to-override-component-providers-in-angular-unit-tests-b73b47b582e3.

Comment: i see.. since you say, i look at the module and sure enough there is a "providers" prop. so i think think this is the issue. seems that this causes prior override in testbed to be clobbered. although you mention is in `Component({`, i find in `@NgModule({`